# How to manage concurrency in docker push and docker pull?

Tags: docker

I have the following scenario:

- A daemon_pulling running `docker pull` the last version of an image from a private registry.

  - E.g. `docker pull localhost:5000/myimage:v1` # sha or image id: 1234
- A daemon_pushing running `docker push` of the last version of a image.

  - E.g. `docker commit container_stable localhost:5000/myimage:v1 && docker push localhost:5000/myimage:v1` # sha or image id: 6789

The code works fine to deploy images based on containers!

The problem is when a `dameon_pushing` (sha or image id: 6789) is running and run a `daemon_pulling` (sha or image id: 1234) at the same time, because the pushing (6789) is not finished when a docker pull (1234) is used and detect a local change (6789 != 1234) and try download the image (1234) again but my last stable image is pushing (6789)...

I'm looking for a way to push without affect a pull in progress, and vice versa.

What is a better way to manage this concurrency?

I tried using a different Docker image name as pivot and rename it directly on the registry server, but I didn't find a way to rename remotely (just local rename).

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this setup/workflow?

Comment: @jonatan We have a CI that detect changes in a branch stables and branch of pull request... then the builds of pull request use `docker pull stable` and the changes in stable branch use `docker push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have set up your CI build to pull an existing image, run a container from it and install the updates, commit the changes to the same image name and then push it back to the registry. Continuously updating images by running containers and committing to the same image is not a good practice, since it hides the changes, and makes it unnecessarily difficult to replicate the build.

A better way would be to build the image from a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), where you define all build steps. Look at the Reference Architecture on Docker's official [Continuous Integration use case](https://www.docker.com/use-cases/continuous-integration) for examples. If you want to shorten build times, you can make your own [base image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/) to start from.

Comment: thanks for reply. My CI use a Dockerfile with all git repository of production `git clone production/8.0` if stable branch `production/8.0` is updated then a new `docker build` is executed. However, with the pull request try use the last version `docker pull` (PR don't execute `docker push`) but the issue is when the CI is executing a `docker push` and a PR come with `docker pull`. I will review the links. Thank you!